# How to calculate subtotal and show heading in sql server reporting 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have data like picture below

[image]

I want to display my data like this
[image]

So I want to know how can i show group 01 02 03 and then calculate their respective totals in sql server reporting 2008 R2.

Is there any built-in technique to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a group with the expression below

```
=Mid(Fields!Code.Value,1,2)
```

Mid is similar to sql Substring function